# How to iterate through data and display them in JSX in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, jsx

I have a function that makes a call to the server and retrieves data in a form of `array of json objects`, what i want is to iterate through the data and display them in the `JSX` .

**Thw Problem is**
No thing is being displayed on the screen, not even getting an error. and when I `console.log` the response i got this:

[image]

**below is the component**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Supplier(){

    let suppliers_list=[];

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getAllSuppliers();
    });


    const getAllSuppliers = () =>{
        return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/supplier',supplierData).then(
            response=>{
                let allSuppliers = response.data;

                allSuppliers.forEach(element => {
                    suppliers_list.push(
                    <li>{element.supplier_name}</li>
                    );
                });

            },error =>{
                //handle error
            }
        );
    }


    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {suppliers_list}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Supplier;
```

and when I `console.log` the `suppliers_list` I got this:

[image]

Comment: You should be using the `useState` hook for your `suppliers_list`. Declaring it as a var means it is not reactive so your component will ignore changes to it.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I am new to `Reactjs` please can you answer it? i tried to use `useState` but i got error `Objects are not valid as a React child`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like below,

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Supplier(){

    const [suppliersList, setSuppliersList] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getAllSuppliers();
    }, []); // Hoping you want to execute getAllSuppliers function only once, so [] empty square braces 


    const getAllSuppliers = () =>{
        return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/supplier', supplierData).then(
            response=>{
                setSuppliersList(response.data);
            },error =>{
                //handle error
            }
        );
    }


    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {suppliersList.map(supplierObject => {
                return <li>{supplierObject.supplier_name}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Supplier;
```